# Only explicit form of state reset works on React Controlled Form; is there a less verbose way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I'm relatively new both to JavaScript and React.

I'm trying to get hold of controlled forms, both by Class and Function/Hooks.

Trying a [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-handle-multiple-input-field-in-react-form-with-a-single-function/) code, I added a reset to form fields after submitting, and here [is my working example](https://codepen.io/msdiniz-the-sasster/pen/OJwQmdR?editors=1010).

My problem, as I said in the Title, is that I can only reset the Form if I provide empty strings for all fields:

```
this.setState({
  email: "",
  name: "",
  age: "",
  address: "",
  phoneNo: "",
  zip: "",
  city: "",
  state: ""
});
```

But before, intuitively I tough that because I had at constructor:

```
   constructor(props){
    super(props)
    const initValues = {email:'',name:'', age:'', address:'',phoneNo:'',
        zip:'', city:'', state:''};
    this.state = {initValues}
```

I should be able to:

```
    //Does not work:
    this.setState( {initValues});
```

or:

```
    //Still does not work:
    this.setState(() => {
       initValues;
    });
```

I even tried this dumb way:

```
       //Does not work, obviously:
       this.state = { initValues };
```

I know that there are better ways to do Forms in React, like Formik or React-Forms, but I'm trying to get hold of older ways before move to more abstract and modern ways.
But if I have a Form with, say, 35 fields, this is insane.

What am I missing?

TIA

Comment: are you using useState?

Comment: @titleLogin, no, in this example I'm using Class, so I think that I cannot use Hooks in a easy way. The complete and functioning code is [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-handle-multiple-input-field-in-react-form-with-a-single-function/)

Comment: you wanna to get the values from the form?

Comment: @titleLogin, I'm currently accessing the form's values through `this.state`, both during the form's fields filling and after submitting it.